# sql trigger to update based on specific column is updated and if value is equal to 'x'

Tags: sql-server

Basically I have a nvarchar column names MyTargetColumn, I want the trigger to do an update but only if that column is effected and the column's new value = 'x'

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytestTrigger
   ON myTable
   after UPDATE
AS
IF (Update (MyTargetColumn) AND MyTargetColumn = 'x')
```

doesnt seem to fire, am I missing something?

Comment: What does mean `doesn't seem to fire`? Your trigger don't fire?

Comment: Do you want the update to happen even if the column was already = 'x'? Also what is "the update"?

Comment: If it doesn't fire then your trigger could be disabled. Please add to your question the trigger's source code .

Answer (score 4):

```
IF(UPDATE(MyTargetColumn))
BEGIN
    UPDATE t SET col1= GETDATE()
               FROM table t
    INNER JOIN Inserted I on t.colname=I.colname
    WHERE I.colname='X'
END
```

Try to join with Inserted table and then mention the condition in the where clause.